# Grid issue with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a simple page using Bootstrap. The problem I have now is related to the grid system.

I needed a main div contain two divs. So I created a main div with class of `row-fluid`. The inside two divs were given classes of `soan4` and `span8`, respectively. The problem I have now is that the two divs are not shown properly. Please take a look at the end result: http://i61.tinypic.com/2rgneci.png

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sticky footer &middot; Twitter Bootstrap</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- CSS -->
    <style type="text/css">

    .border{
        border: 2px solid;
    }
    </style>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div class="row-fluid">

       <!-- sidebar start -->
       <div class="sidebar border span4" >
          1 </div> 
       <!-- sidebar end -->

       <!-- content start -->
       <div class="blogBody border span8">
          2 </div> 
       <!-- content end -->

    </div><!-- main div end -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What version of bootstrap is that??? o.O
Take a look to this http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid
There you have the correct documentation.

As far as I know, there's no "span8" - "soan4" CSS selectors

Comment: Yes, changed it to col-**-* notation. Problem is still present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since bootstrap 3 the syntax changed:
span does't exist now it's col-width_wanted-number_of_columns
so for you something like this  :

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="sidebar border col-xs-4" >
1
</div> <!-- sidebar end -->
<!-- content start -->
<div class="blogBody border col-xs-8">
2
</div> <!-- content end -->
</div><!-- main dev end -->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z22oxbap/

For more ressource look here : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid
EDIT:

`-xs-` is for extra small device (<768px) width
`-sm-` is for small device between (≥768px) and (<992px) width
`-md-` is for desktop device between (≥992px) and (<1200px) width
`-lg-` is for large device more than (≥1200px) width

Comment: +1 but it's worth mentioning that `-xs-` is for mobile devices and inherits to bigger devices if no other class is present: *Grid classes apply to devices with screen widths greater than or equal to the breakpoint sizes, and override grid classes targeted at smaller devices. Therefore, applying any .col-md- class to an element will not only affect its styling on medium devices but also on large devices if a .col-lg- class is not present.*

Comment: Tried it. The two inner divs floated to the left: http://i57.tinypic.com/140ad1i.png

Comment: Can you paste all css file. I think a declaration must change how `.blogBody` is displayed.

Comment: There is no CSS file at the current moment.